# Grails and gsp: How to render nested template with the same model/bean?

Tags: templates, grails, nested, render, gsp

maybe I am just asking google & co. the wrong questions but this is what I want to accomplish:

I have a GSP template with a nested template within. The outer one has access to the members of a domain class instance. Instead of passing all the domain member like

```
<g:render template="/image/alternativeTemplate" model="${[member1: member1, member2: member2]}"/>
```

or using the iterator like

```
<g:render template="/image/alternativeTemplate" model="${[it: it]}"/>
```

i would like to do simply use outer GSP's model in the inner one.

Am I missing something?

Greetings,
smon

Comment: How do you use model in your template?

Comment: Do you have a similar problem or was this a response to my question to Joshua Moore's comment? I used it in the inner template like in the outer one.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you use model, not bean. I want to know, how to use bean instead of model

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To expose the entire model to a template for rendering use `pageScope.variables` such as:

```
<g:render template="/some/template" model="${pageScope.variables}"/>
```

Comment: Very nice way to pass entire model. Didn't know about this. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I am still unable to access the passed model. Just like `${member1 }`?

Comment: Post your code for how you are constructing your model in your controller as well as any error messages or what result you are getting when you try and access something in the model from your template.

Comment: I got it, your solution worked - I had another problem. Thank you very much.